# How to find smallest row total and display corresponding name in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I find the employee the worked the least number of hours and display their name and total hours worked?

I can't seem to figure out how to display the name (i.e. Employee 2, Employee 3, or etc.) and the least number of hours worked is always equalled to zero.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EmpHrsWrkd {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] employees =
         {
         "Employee 1",
         "Employee 2",
         "Employee 3",
         "Employee 4",
         "Employee 5",
         "Employee 6",
         };

      int[][] hrsWrkd =
         {
         { 5, 8, 6, 2 },
         { 2, 0, 8, 6 },
         { 6, 4, 9, 5 },
         { 7, 8, 8, 4 },
         { 3, 6, 2, 8 },
         { 9, 5, 1, 7 },
         };

    // Calculate the rows and columns in 2D array
      final int EMPLOYEES = hrsWrkd.length;
      final int HOURS = hrsWrkd[0].length;

      // Find employee that worked least number of hours
      int min = hrsWrkd[0][0];
      for (int col = 0; col < hrsWrkd.length; col++) {
         for (int row = 0; row < hrsWrkd[col].length; row++) { 
            if (min > hrsWrkd[col][row]) {
               min = hrsWrkd[col][row];
            }
         }
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, min);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you share the actual and the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your code you're comparing single hours and not sum of it for every employee. It's always 0, because the smallest number in your matrix is 0.

To do this right first you have to sum hours for every employee and then compare it to get validate result. As shown below:

```
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int employeeWithMinValue = -1;
    for (int col = 0; col < hrsWrkd.length; col++) {
        int tempSum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < hrsWrkd[col].length; row++) {
            tempSum = tempSum + hrsWrkd[col][row];
        }
        if (tempSum < minValue) {
            minValue = tempSum;
            employeeWithMinValue = col;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee number " + employeeWithMinValue +
            " worked only " + minValue + " hours");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Any idea why the employee number is always one step down than it should be? Employee 2 should have the least hours worked, not 1

Comment: It's because employee position in hrsWrkd matrix starts from 0. So in fact Employee 2 has position number 1 in your Array. To change it you can just add +1 in your result.